# Firebase Simple Login does not monitor logout in different window

Tags: firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I have application which stores user state into localStorage and propagate app model changes into all browser windows/tabs. But I can't figure out how to propagate logout/login into different window. FirebaseSimpleLogin callback is called only per window. I can detect user login status with localStorage, but how to get FirebaseSimpleLogin callback runned?
If I create new instance of FirebaseSimpleLogin, it works but it also leaks. So for now I have to reload application in second tab to get actual user login state.

Comment: Browser windows do not share login state. This is a fundamental part of how browsers work and their security model.

Comment: They share it across windows with the same origin policy. So when user of app open link into another window, then cookie is shared too. So FirebaseSimpleLogin should deal with that.

Comment: Fair enough. In which case, this sounds like a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kato mentions in the comment above, this is not a feature that Firebase Simple Login supports. If you'd like to file this, or anything else, as a feature request please email the [Firebase support team directly](https://www.firebase.com/docs/help/).